# Users managing on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, administrator, privileges

I have a Windows 10 Pro edition, and I want to make *Administrator accounts* but still have one *Super Admin* which is the only one that can reset and create new users.

The scenario :

- Myaccount: All privileges
- Other admin accounts: All privileges except creating new admin users or reset passwords, this is to make them able to install apps and do admin actions without being able to create new users.

Comment: You're already handing them the keys to the castle why bother attaching a post-it note? As far as I know this is not supported. You could look into using group policies (assuming the machine is part of a domain) or local policies to enable normal users to install software. Which again would pretty much just hand them the keys.

Comment: This is not possible. Please rethink what you are trying to do.